# Does Progress-4GL have color constants?

Tags: colors, openedge, progress-4gl

In my application, I need to modify the colour of a widget.

When I look into my application, I see following lines of code:

```
BGCOLOR 25 FGCOLOR 24 .
BGCOLOR 21 FGCOLOR 20 .
BGCOLOR  8 FGCOLOR 24 .
... (and many more)
```

This is, of course, very unreadable.

Does Progress-4GL have any colour constants, like `clRed`, `clGreen`, ..., I can use for readability reasons? In case not, is there any online "cheat sheet" for this subject?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability use either `enum` or `preprocessors` to define what your intended colors are based on how you have defined your colors in your ini file or registry.

```
// color.cls
enum color:

   define enum
      black       = 0
      dark-blue   = 1
      dark-green  = 2
      dark-cyan   = 3
      dark-red    = 4
      dark-purple = 5
      
      // ...      
      
      white = 15
      .

end enum.
```

Unfortunately the enum is not automatically cast to its integer value when needed for fgcolor:

```
define frame fr
with
   bgcolor integer( color:dark-purple )
   .
   
view frame fr.
wait-for close of frame fr.
```

With preprocessors this is a bit simpler:

```
// color.i
&global define color-black        0
...
&global define color-dark-purple  5
&global define color-white       15
```

And then use them:

```
{ color.i }

define frame fr
with
   bgcolor {&color-dark-purple}
   .
   
view frame fr.
wait-for close of frame fr.
```

Comment: As we're using Progress-4GL in a non-object oriented way, I prefer the way of the preprocessor includes.

Answer (score 1):

Not really constants. But the color numbers refer to RGB values in the progress.ini or Windows registry.

In the progress.ini file it's in the [Colors] section:

```
[Colors]
;******************************************************************************
; THE DEFINITION OF COLOR 0 THROUGH 15 IS PRIVATE TO THE PROGRESS ADE.  
; MODIFYING COLORS 0 THROUGH 15 MAY PREVENT THE PROGRESS ADE FROM RUNNING.
; The following color definitions correspond to the ADE standards.
;  0 to 15  - reserved
color0=0,0,0
color1=0,0,128
color2=0,128,0
color3=0,128,128
color4=128,0,0
color5=128,0,128
color6=128,128,0
color7=128,128,128
color8=192,192,192
color9=0,0,255
color10=0,255,0
color11=0,255,255
color12=255,0,0
color13=255,0,255
color14=255,255,0
color15=255,255,255
```

Or in the Registry (e.g. in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\PROGRESS\11.7\Colors:

[image]

If your runtime uses ini or registry is based on startup parameter -basekey ini -ininame .

Colors 0 to 15 *should* not be modified.